# Swift - Why is my application finding nil in this scenario

Tags: swift

I have an tableView which loads cells from a xib file. The cells contain 2 labels, 1 shows the quantity and the second shows the price. The quantity is pulled from a static model and works just fine, and the price is pulled from a model which is populated from the result of a URLSession. Below is my cellForRowAt function which works fine in this scenario:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let item: BasketModel = cellItems[indexPath.row] as! BasketModel
    let ordersCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("OrderTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! OrderTableViewCell

    ordersCell.priceLabel.text = item.price
    ordersCell.quantityLabel.text = String(basketStruct.getQty(id: item.id!))
            return ordersCell
}
```

My cell shows as follows Qty: 3         Price: 0.70

Now, the problem I have is, when i alter the line above where I set the price label to the following:

```
ordersCell.priceLabel.text = String(basketStruct.getQty(id: item.id!) * Int(item.price!)!)
```

I get the error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What I want, is the qty to be multiplied by the price. However, when I try to use item.price for anything I have to force unwrap it and then I get my error.

How would I go about this ?

Comment: The price is `0.70`, are you sure it can be converted to an `Int`?

Comment: Just safely unwrap values and in guards/if lets systematically debug where the value should already been assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that `item.price` is nil, but `Int(item.price!)` is nil.

From your question, you said that the price displayed is `0.70`, so I suppose `item.price` must contain the string `"0.70"`.

Well, `0.70` is not a valid `Int`, so when you try to parse it as an `Int`, it evaluates to `nil`.

I think you meant `Double(item.price!)!`.

As a good practise, you should always check for invalid number strings:

```
if let price = Double(item.price!) {
    // ...
} else {
    print("Invalid price: \(item.price!)")
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I feel ridiculous. Thankyou for this. Missed the obvious :') Once SO allows me, I'll mark this as the answer.